# Convert User Input to Milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, gettime

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a User Input date to Milliseconds.

These are the expected input types:

```
var case1 = "2015-12-25";
var case2 = 1450137600;
var case3 = "1450137600abcdefg";
```

It needs to accept either input type and convert it to milliseconds. Or if there's text it returns null.

These are the expected outputs:

```
case1: 1451001600000
case2: 1450137600
case3: null
```

Current code:

```
app.get('/api/timestamp/:input', function (req, res) { //User input something. Case 1, 2, and 3.
   let user_input = req.params.input;
   let new_date = new Date(user_input);
   let unix = new_date.getTime();
   let utc = new_date.toUTCString();
   res.json({"user_input": user_input, "unix": unix, "utc": utc})
```

Live example:

```
https://periodic-nightingale.glitch.me/api/timestamp/2015-12-25
https://periodic-nightingale.glitch.me/api/timestamp/1450137600
https://periodic-nightingale.glitch.me/api/timestamp/1450137600abcdefg
https://periodic-nightingale.glitch.me/
```

Working solution:

```
app.get('/api/timestamp/:input', function (req, res) { //User input something. Case 1, 2, and 3. 
  let user_input = req.params.input;

   if(!isNaN(user_input)) { //User input is a string, not a number. Case 1.
     user_input = parseInt(user_input) * 1000; 
   }

  let unix = new Date(user_input).getTime(); //Converts user_input to a Unix timestamp.
  let utc = new Date(user_input).toUTCString(); //Converts user_input to a UTC timestamp.

  res.json({"unix": unix, "utc": utc})
})
```

Comment: so what did you attempt? Seems like two different problems.

Comment: I've been trying combinations of new date and getTime(). If I run the code by itself it works fine. But when I try to duplicate the process on the Node.js server it is returning "null" as result for case2.

Comment: case 2 looks like it is milliseconds so you would test if it is a number and if it is, just return that.

Comment: I also need to convert the milliseconds to a date (date.toUTCString()) for the next part of the assignment. It doesn't seem to work if I try entering a number there, instead of a date.

Comment: "*Or if there's text it returns NaN.*", so why do you expect *null*? :-)

Comment: Problem is `"1450137600"` is not the same as `1450137600`, so detect the format and than convert it to a number.

Comment: OHH! It's not a number, it's a string!! That really helped, I just needed to convert the case2 input into a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add code to detect a number and handle it accordingly.

- First one should work find with new Date in most engines.
- Second one needs to be a number, not a string `"1450137600"` is not equivalent to `1450137600` with `new Date()`.
- Third, well if two tests fail, that this means it must be bad...

So the basic code

```
function foo (str) {

  if ((/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/).test(str)) { // if ####-##-##
    return new Date(str);
  } else if ((/^\d+$/).test(str)) {  // if #######
    return new Date(+str);  // convert string to number
  } else {
    throw new Error("Invalid format")
  }
}
```

Comment: I did something different, but you were right about the input being a string not a number. Thanx again, it's working now!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simple as this:

```
new Date("2015-12-25").getTime()
```

Comment: I'm running the code in Node.js and getting the user input with req.params.input. For some reason that code works in case1, but not in case2. The value is returning null. If I run it in Codepen it works, so I don't really understand why I can't get it working on the server.

Comment: case2 is seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: It seems to be a Unix timestamp measured in seconds, since January 1st 1970.

Comment: No it's not. Most browsers will parse it as UTC, some as local. **Don't use the built–in parser**.

Comment: Is new Date the built-in parser? Should I be using body-parser instead? I'm using that in another project where the user POSTs the data to the next page.